# Elastic Beanstalk ebextension adding multiple SSHSourceRestrictions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I am trying to get my Elastic Beanstalk Security Group to allow 2 SSH port 22 ip addresses to access it.  I want to do this with .ebextension.   I am able to get one, but I can't figure out how to do two.

I have tried a lot of variations but can't get it to work.

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: SSHSourceRestriction
    value: tcp,22,22,xx.xxx.8.0/21,1xx.xxx.0.0/16
```

and (okay, I knew the next one would not work, but I am grasping)

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: SSHSourceRestriction
    value: tcp,22,22,xx.xxx.8.0/21
    value: tcp,22,22,xx.xxx.0.0/16
```

I am also tried putting each value into a separate file but in the end, I still just have one SSH port.